# MySQL returns not logical id's

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Today I was working on some MySQL query exercises and I come up with one of the weirder results. The image says more than a thousand words. I have no idea why this is happening so if anyone understands what is causing this issue or what I misunderstood about MySQL behavior, I would be very grateful for an explanation. I am expecting 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 from the first query. Thank you.

[image: Mysql strange results]

Comment: put order by and see if the same result shows

Comment: Please don't just put an image and claim that the problem is obvious. Images are not searchable. Doing this will cause your question to get down voted.

Comment: Well, I am not claiming the problem is obvious, I said what results I am expecting from this query and that I don't understand what is causing results like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DB is designed to grab the data as fast as possible.

If you don't add a specific order to your query then why should the DB waste time and order the data?

#### There is no garanteed order without an `order by` clause.

Comment: "DB will return the results in the way it grabs them as fast as possible"

This makes sense, but what I am wondering is why it happens even if I select 2 columns, but when 3 are included the results are good.

Is the reason same?

Comment: For the very specifics why it grabbed the data like this you would have to analize the source code of MySQL. Sometimes it is the fastest way to grab the data according to an index and since the ID is the primary key it grabs them in that order. But not garanteed

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for an explanation, helped me a lot to understand.